# How to extend image across width of screen?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am attempting to make the images scroll horizontally. I downloaded some UI, and added ScrollView horizontal. But instead of it looking the same just with the ability to scroll horizontally, it shrank the image (and also gave it the ability to scroll horizontally). What should I change to make it stretch all the way across (still with the padding)?

[image]

Posts.js

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  ImagBackground,
  ImageBackground,
} from "react-native";
import Icon from "@expo/vector-icons/Entypo";
import { ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

export default class Posts extends React.Component {
  state = {
    liked: false,
  };
  onLike = () => {
    this.setState({ liked: !this.state.liked });
  };
  render() {
    const { name, profile, photo, onPress } = this.props;

    return (
      <View>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            paddingTop: 25,
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <View style={{ width: "20%" }}>
            <Image
              source={profile}
              style={{
                width: 45,
                height: 45,
                borderRadius: 13,
              }}
            />
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              width: "60%",
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                fontFamily: "Bold",
                fontSize: 14,
                color: "#044244",
              }}
            >
              {name}
            </Text>

            <Text
              style={{
                fontFamily: "Medium",
                fontSize: 12,
                color: "#9ca1a2",
              }}
            >
              2 mins ago
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              width: "20%",
              alignItems: "flex-end",
            }}
          >
            <Icon name="sound-mix" color="#044244" size={20} />
          </View>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            width: "100%",
            paddingTop: 20,
          }}
        >
          <ScrollView horizontal>
            <ImageBackground
              source={photo}
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: 220,
              }}
              imageStyle={{
                borderRadius: 30,
              }}
            >
              <View
                style={{
                  height: "100%",
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  alignItems: "flex-end",
                  justifyContent: "flex-end",
                }}
              >
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={onPress}
                  style={{
                    marginBottom: 20,
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    padding: 5,
                    backgroundColor: "#e8e8e8",
                  }}
                >
                  <Icon name="forward" color="#044244" size={20} />
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={this.onLike}
                  style={{
                    marginBottom: 20,
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    padding: 5,
                    backgroundColor: "#e8e8e8",
                    marginLeft: 10,
                    marginRight: 20,
                  }}
                >
                  <Icon
                    name={
                      this.state.liked === true ? "heart" : "heart-outlined"
                    }
                    color={this.state.liked === true ? "red" : "#044244"}
                    size={20}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </ImageBackground>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's me adding more words because the post doesn't have enough words on it's own. When will they finally remove this pointless feature? I feel as if I clearly expressed my question with the few words I used.

Answer (score 0):

- I believe your issue is with your `View` wrapping your `ScrollView`. There is no need of wrapping `ScrollView`, that too in `row`, due to which the remaining space is visible. Just define the `ScrollView`, and it would work just fine. Give a width of `100%` to your `ScrollView` though.
- For any sort of styling to the parent for the `ScrollView`, do it inside the `ScrollView` itself, like the way I did in the code.
- Please note **ScrollView accepts a list of child items**, currently I see only a single item, if you've intentionally added this one, then it is fine, else, you need to refactor your code surely. This won't work out for you.

```js
        // PLEASE NOTE --> Commented Lines should be removed, and 
        // only ScrollView should be considered with the styling specified
        // <View
          // style={{
            // flexDirection: "row",
            // width: "100%",
            // paddingTop: 20,
          // }}
        // >
          <ScrollView horizontal 
          style={{ 
              width: '100%', 
              marginTop: 20, 
              paddingLeft: 16, 
              paddingRight: 6
          }}>
            <ImageBackground
              source={photo}
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: 220,
                marginRight: 10
              }}
              imageStyle={{
                borderRadius: 30,
              }}
            >
              <View
                style={{
                  height: "100%",
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  alignItems: "flex-end",
                  justifyContent: "flex-end",
                }}
              >
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={onPress}
                  style={{
                    marginBottom: 20,
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    padding: 5,
                    backgroundColor: "#e8e8e8",
                  }}
                >
                  <Icon name="forward" color="#044244" size={20} />
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={this.onLike}
                  style={{
                    marginBottom: 20,
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    padding: 5,
                    backgroundColor: "#e8e8e8",
                    marginLeft: 10,
                    marginRight: 20,
                  }}
                >
                  <Icon
                    name={
                      this.state.liked === true ? "heart" : "heart-outlined"
                    }
                    color={this.state.liked === true ? "red" : "#044244"}
                    size={20}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </ImageBackground>
          </ScrollView>
        // </View>
```